# how to reduce truth table with large number of input variables

Tags: algorithm, digital, digital-logic

Algos to reduce the expression generated by truth table having number of input variable greater then 6.

---

More generic question would be::
Algos to reduce the expression generated by truth table having number of input variable n  :where n > 6

Comment: Not sure why this question was closed. It is related to boolean minimisation in logic tables. I actually found it via google when looking for answers myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm thinking that once you get up past that number of inputs there is no good way to do it analytically.  You'll probably have to fall back on heuristic methods.

Have you tried Espresso? From my experience it works very well, take a look: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Espresso_heuristic_logic_minimizer

Though you may be able to do some Boolean Algebra on the expression, it's most likely going to be difficult to figure whether it's in simplest form or not with that many variables.